# Edit Excel sheet in a python loop

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I can edit an Excel file with xlwings:

```
import xlwings as xw

filepath = ('file.xlsx')
wb = xw.Workbook(filepath)

sh = 'Sheet1'
l = ['B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11']

for i in range(len(l)):
    xw.Range(sh, l[i]).value = i
```

How can I iterate over rows without having to write a list by Hand? In Addition, is there a way to iterate over columns?

Edit: Editing a cell range works now.

```
import xlwings as xw

filepath = ('file.xlsx')
wb = xw.Workbook(filepath)

sh = 'Sheet1'
l = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

for i in range(len(l)):
    xw.Range(sh , (3,2),(10,2)).value = l[i]
```

[image]

Problem: Every cell is changed in the process. How can I Change one, then move to the next?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to assign the values manually anyway?, can you put an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out. Will Edit the question in a sec.

Comment: I'm assuming your problem could be solved with something like the code i implied on my edit.

Comment: Your code snippet puts a value in every cell, doesnt it? Isnt that the same Thing that my edit section does? I want to edit a cell in a for Loop, then move to the next.

Comment: xw.Range(sh , (3,2),(10,2)).value = 1, assigns the value automatically 
 to all those cells, the approach that i'm sharing lets you change the value at every cell on Range(sh , (3,2),(10,2)), isn't that what you want? if not, can you share what "Edit a cell then move to the next" means?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to put an Excel cell edit command into a python for Loop, so that with every Iteration one of many cells will be edited. One by one. Like a normal python Iteration.

Comment: Excel Manipulation with python seems to not be that wide spread. I am going to work through the documentation. Thanks

Comment: Let me try an approach on my own, if i stumble upon it, I'll share it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there's a way to it, however i'll highly encourge you to read the [documentation](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=Range#range), and try it youself.

Here's a hint of what you are looking for:

**Range**

**class** xlwings.Range(cell1=None, cell2=None, **options)
*Returns a Range object that represents a cell or a range of cells.*

**Parameters**: 
*cell1* (str or tuple or Range) – *Name of the range in the upper-left corner in A1 notation or as index-tuple or as name or as xw.Range object. It can also* specify a range using the range operator (a colon), .e.g. ‘A1:B2’
cell2 (str or tuple or Range, default None) – Name of the range in the lower-right corner in A1 notation or as index-tuple or as name or as xw.Range object.

**Edit:**

Isn't Range() an iterable object? if so, you can use like this:

```
for cell in Range(sh , (3,2),(10,2)):
    cell.value = 10
```